# Can I access the source code of a PuTTY telnet server?

Tags: server, telnet, putty

I'm sorry, I don't know how to phrase my question better.
For homework, I've been given a telnet server IP and Port that I connect to with PuTTY.
I was wondering if it is possible to view the source code of that server?
It is my first time learning about telnet and using PuTTY, and I don't know anything about it. I was just wondering if it is possible to view the source code of a telnet server, and if it is, how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: The server is just another computer so doesn't have "source code" as its not a program.
Yet, when you use telnet to connect to a server an interactive terminal is opened. 
This is the window with a text prompt that you see, and it is a way of interacting with the remote server.
If you mean that server has some code stored on it you can navigate the folders and files on that server using the terminal. (See, for example, https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/navigating-filesystem-linux-terminal)

Comment: @SamBob I don't feel like "the server is just another computer" is a useful or even valid thing to say here.  The computer is called a server, but so is the process on that computer accepting incoming connections, and that program absolutely has source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the idea behind this question is that if you're looking at a webpage you can do "view source" in the browser and look at the HTML, CSS, and Javascript that make up that page.

Of course, what you're seeing there is just the "client side" part of the web page.  You can't click "view source" on Facebook and see the code that accesses their database, decides what to show in your feed, picks out the ads you're going see, etc., because that's all done server-side.  Nor can you see the source code for the web server that handles your incoming connection, etc.

In the case of a telnet server, the "client side" portion is just the raw text you're seeing.  There's nothing [1] analogous to what you'd see if you did "view source" in a browser beyond what you're already seeing in your telnet window.

Of course, if the program that they're running on the server side is publicly available, you may be able to download and read its source code.  This is analogous to how, if a web site is running on apache or nginx, you can just download the source code for those and read them.  But this is not something that's sent over the telnet connection.

---

[1] Slight nitpick: I guess technically if the text you're seeing has VT100 control sequences to highlight or colorize the text that is sort of analogous to HTML code, but it's *very* limited.  If that's what you want to know about, you could either set your telnet client not to process those sequences in order to see what they look like, or you could capture the network traffic with something like tcpdump.  But you can also just look up VT100 control sequences.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.